# enabling virtual hosts in apache 2.4 or later

Tags: virtualization, apache-2.4, host

I'm using apache http server 2.4 on debian 8.

I seem to recall from a few years ago that if you wanted to have virtual hosts, you have to enable this by adding a line to your main apache config file. Has this changed?

I can't seem to find that line in the main config file and yet the `000-default.conf` virtual host is working.

I just wanted to confirm, are virtual hosts now enabled by default in this version of apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of vhosts is enabled by default, you can create new vhosts in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`  and enable it by using `a2ensite <vhostfile name>`.

This will create a symlink from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` to the corresponding vhost in sites-available.

Note that in jessie vhosts should end in `.conf`